# Angular Memory leak Destroy nested directive manually by recursion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, memory-leaks, destroy

I have a lot of nested directives in my system

I'm using angular 1.2.10V and i have a memory leaks.
i test the 1.4.8 version with a new version of chrome and found that using in both together solve almost all the memory leaks. but unfortunately i can't upgrade to neither versions due to technical issues in my organization.

alternativly i found that if i call the directive destroy recursivly from most nested children directive upward to the target directive which i want to destroy. it's solve almost all the memory leak even in my old angular and old chrome version.

Technically beside that it's against the angular destroy implementation concept i don't see any problem to use this code and in fact i didn't found any exceptional problems in my system after i implemented this code. but i want to be sure that it will not create a problems in the future, in assuming that we will not going to upgrade to any new angular or chrome version.

I'd like to get more opinions..

Comment: Are you unregistering all $watch and $on listeners on $destroy? That ought to do it.

Comment: Yes i'm doing this already but my goal is to prevent memory leaks in global  way. which mean to prevent case when a developer forgot to unregistering watchers or listeners so i will do it instead.
(i have a complex system with a lot of directives and i can't verified that the developers clean after themselfs)